# Setting up localhost

Tags: xpages, xpinc

System Specs: Windows 7; Notes/Desinger: 9.0; ExtLib: most current version

Trying to test my XPages on my localhost, but everything I have found and tried has failed.  I updated the local security to allow both localhost and 127.0.0.1.  I updated the host file so the localhost line wasn't commented out.  I changed some registry setting.  The only thing I have yet to do is create local server machines and install domino server because I don't have the server license to do that.

Anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: Install Domino locally or test against a remote Domino server. Using the preview option against a true local replica **WILL** produce misleading results. This causes many developers to waste many hours trying to figure out why the users aren't seeing what the developer sees, when the reason is simply that the users are accessing a Domino server and the developer is not.

Comment: Good information to know whenever I actually succeed at getting localhost to work

Comment: What's your progress?

Comment: @stwissel I cannot install locally on work PC and don't currently have a server file to install at home.

Comment: How is the exact status? A) anything else running on Port 80 (use netstat to check). Can you preview a classic design element? Do log or trace show any error. My bet is on blocked port. What do you get when you curl -v http://127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 2):

Tim is right: you want to use a local server if you do serious development, but you need to sort out the licensing. The biggest headache for local preview is, that you only access your database as anonymous (there might be in future a LocalPreviewUseNotesid=1 notes.ini parameter, but that hasn't been confirmed on any roadmap).

The caveats on a Windows Vista/7/8/81 install to watch out for:

- Don't have your data directory in Program Files (as the default install suggests). If there: uninstall Designer and reinstall. Pick a location in your userprofile (like the shared install of a Notes client only)
- A lot of AV products, as well as Skype like to block Port 80. Either hunt them down or use the Designer preferences to use a different port
- Designer loads all plug-ins from [programdir]\framework\eclipse and [datadir]workspace\eclipse while the local preview uses [datadir]\domino\workspace\eclipse. You might need to copy missing features/plug-ins there. The install instructions of the Extlib from OpenNTF go into details about that
- As Kevin mentioned, the UAC might be an issue

Good luck and let us know how it goes!

Comment: I did read one of your blog posts about using localhost which helped.  I haven't did an uninstall/reinstall so I guess I will give that a try and see if that works until I am ready to buy a domino license.  At this time anonymous will be fine since I am testing with DB2 data

Comment: You are welcome to accept the answer :-) -- you might be in for some surprises with Anonymous and JDBC access

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure but when you executed your program did you pick "Run as Administrator"?  It's possible UAC is not allowing it to do it's thing because it's not running in priviledge mode.

I may be totally off with this but thought I would try to help.  Good Luck.

Comment: I did try to run as administrator